# Android: Layout List header

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have a header for a list that contains two image buttons. I want one of those image buttons to be on the left, and the other to be on the right. This is what my xml file looks like right now but it does not work, it just puts the two image buttons on the left together. I have also tried without the additional LinearLayouts but no luck.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
  android:background="@drawable/list_header_background">
    <LinearLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:gravity="left"
      android:background="@drawable/list_header_background">
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/refreshBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_refresh"
            android:background="@drawable/list_header_background"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:gravity="right"
      android:background="@drawable/list_header_background">
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/battleBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_battle"
            android:background="@drawable/list_header_background"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As kabuko wrote, the `RelativeLayout` width is equal to the parent width. When we have a child view inside that `RelativeLayout`, we can use the `android:layout_alignParentXXXXXX="true"` parameter in order to align it (the child) accordingly to the parent.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:background="@drawable/list_header_background">
  <ImageButton
      android:id="@+id/refreshBtn"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:padding="4dp"
      android:src="@drawable/ic_refresh"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:background="@drawable/list_header_background"
  />
  <ImageButton
      android:id="@+id/battleBtn"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:padding="4dp"
      android:src="@drawable/ic_battle"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      android:background="@drawable/list_header_background"
   />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Yes that does work, I am torn on who to give credit on this. kabuko answered first and was "technically" right, but you gave a much more better example.

Comment: It's up to you. I was writing the answer at the same time, though. I'd have been faster if it wasn't the source code. But I've been there, so it's up to you. It doesn't really matter anyway. It's just virtual.

Comment: I decided to give you credit because you had the code example, however, maybe you can add to your answer what it is about your example that makes it work, basically combine your answer with kabuko, just a thought.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use a RelativeLayout with layout_alignParentLeft and layout_alignParentRight on the buttons.

Comment: Okay, I will give that a try, I will report back.